# Where do these RPM timestamp macros come from?

Tags: linux, macros, timestamp, redhat, rpm

I am charged with porting a system from WebLogic to JBoss.  The components of this system are typically packaged as RPMs and deployed on servers running Linux via rpm.

One of the spec files defines the following.

```
MM=%m ; DD=%d ; YY=%y ; HH24=%H ; MI=%M ; SS=%S ; DATETIME=${MM}${DD}${YY}.${HH24}${MI}${SS}
```

which is clearly some sort of timestamp formatting mechanism, the output of which (DATETIME) gets written when log entries are written.

As part of this process is being ported to python (the rpm script will run python), I am trying to understand the source of these macros ( %m, %d, %y ), etc.  It seems that they might be predefined by the rpm program itself.  I can find no explicit documentation of this in the rpm man-pages or through multiple Google attempts, although I do find some hints that this may be the case.

Can someone confirm that these macros are or aren't defined whenever rpm is invoked and provide documentation of same?

**Update: Wumpus Q. Wumbley points out that these look suspiciously like strftime format symbols.  I agree, so then the question becomes, is recognition of strftime format symbols as macros a feature, perhaps undocumented, of rpm?**

Comment: They look suspiciously like [strftime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html) formats

Comment: I would agree with you.  updating post.

Comment: What happens to the DATETIME variable after it gets set? Is it passed to a `date` command like `date +${DATETIME}`? That would be one way to interpret the strftime format without having it supported directly in rpm.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley - there you go again!  You're right.  That's exactly what they're doing.  It looks like I completely misinterpreted the code.  These %expressions aren't macros at all, they're string literals!  The same could have been accomplished with something like DATETIME=%m%d%y.%H%M%S . Duh, and thanks.

Comment: Hey, @WumpusQ.Wumbley, your comment above IS THE ANSWER.  Submit it as an answer and I'll give you the full credit you deserve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%` codes that are used to build DATETIME look like `strftime` formats. If rpm expands time format strings then that fact should be documented somewhere. On the other hand if the spec file passes them to an external command like `date +${DATETIME}` then you just need to see the documentation for that external command.

Comment: thanks.  The ambiguity in the meaning of the % sign in rpm-spec language (and actually, this was in a script called from an rpm spec) confused me but it was just a string literal.  There is no undocumented feature here.  Thanks.